# When printing an AMPscript variable, a space is added before the period. No space in the DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

Just seeing if there are any fixes or alternate ways of printing. I'm just printing a variable like %%=v(@xyz)=%% and it should look like this: "XYZ." but it always prints like - "XYZ ."

There are no spaces in the DE and it appears to be a glitch of sorts. Anyone ever run into this?

Comment: Have you tried putting a 'TRIM' around the variable to cut off any unwanted spaces? `%%=TRIM(@xyz)=%%` perhaps?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contextual code?